# getJSON With, Then. Not invoking array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using "chart.js"; My data graph is being invoked first and my '$.getJSON' data requests are being reached. I believe I am not correctly pushing my strings into my Array 'ChartData'. My console logs are reaching my desired data strings. Is my syntax incorrect to call a function immediately after my '$.getJSON'? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://zagster-service.herokuapp.com"


const G5_TC = "/rides/count/g5"
const COL_TC = "/rides/count/columbia_simpson"
const DRAKE_TC = "/rides/count/drake_park"
const GALV_TC = "/rides/count/galveston"
const GRC_TC = "/rides/count/grc"
const OLD_TC = "/rides/count/old_mill"
const OSU_TC = "/rides/count/osu_cascades"
const TEN_TC = "/rides/count/ten_barrel"

var ChartData = [];


$(updateView)

function updateView() {

   $.when(
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + G5_TC, updateChartData00), 
            
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + COL_TC, updateChartData01), 
            
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + DRAKE_TC, updateChartData02),
         
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + GALV_TC, updateChartData03),
                    
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + GRC_TC, updateChartData04),
    
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + OLD_TC, updateChartData05),
               
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + OSU_TC, updateChartData06),
           
        $.getJSON(BASE_URL + TEN_TC, updateChartData07)
        
   ).then(displayGraph);

}

function updateChartData00(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData01(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData02(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData03(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData04(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData05(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData06(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}

function updateChartData07(data) {
    console.log(data);
ChartData.push(data.count)
}


/*
 Console log Strings 
function updateChartData00(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData01(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData02(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData03(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData04(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData05(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData06(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function updateChartData07(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
function ChartData(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
*/

/* Visualization JS- Source:"https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html" */


function displayGraph() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d')
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["G5", "Columbia/Simpson", "Drake Park", "Galveston", "GRC", "Old Mill", "OSU-Cascades", "Ten Barrel"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Total Count of Rides Per Station',
            data: ChartData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(58,112,42,0.2)',
                'rgba(76,212,40,0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 217, 1)',
                'rgba(76,242,40,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
      
      legend: {
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'white',
                fontSize: 15.5
            }
        },

      scales: {
            xAxes: [{gridLines: {
                      display: false ,
                      color: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.8)'
                   },
                    ticks: {
                      fontColor: 'white',
                      fontSize: 14
                    }
            }]  ,

            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    fontColor: 'white',
                    fontSize: 14
                },
                gridLines: {
                      display: false ,
                      color: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.8)'
                },  
            }]

        }
    }
  
});

}



/* Drop Down Function-Nav Bar  -----**Source**:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp" */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it-----**Source**:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp" //
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
  }
}
```

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */


/* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Lists: Under "Drop-Down button: Portfolio"= "dropbtn" */

ul {
  margin-left: -3.7px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: -2.1px;
}

.dropdown-list {
  list-style-type: circle;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
.body-zagster {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

.body-zagster {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/VhscY63.jpg?1');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

nav,
p {
  font-family: 'KoHo', sans-serif;
}

.box-transp-zagster {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  border-radius: 25px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-transp-footer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  border-radius: 35px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 65em;
}


/* Image Modifiers */

.vis-img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 73%;
  height: 73%;
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link,
.nav-masthead .dropbtn {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.473);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus,
.nav-masthead .dropbtn:hover,
.nav-masthead .dropbtn:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link+.nav-link,
.dropbtn {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Dropdown Button 
 */

.dropbtn {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}


/* Position of dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border-radius: 15px;
  min-width: 10em;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 14px;
  float: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu */

.show {
  display: block;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}


/*
 * Data Visualization Source: "https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html"
 */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="This is Zagster bike share data">
  <meta name="author" content="Felipe C Arreola">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/wdOId0h.png">

  <title>Zagster Bike Share in Bend</title>

  <!--Data Visualization (DV)
           Source: "https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html"-->

  <!--DV JavaScript-->

  <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <!--DV core CSS-->

  <!--JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=KoHo|Nanum+Gothic|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="body-zagster">

  <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">

    <header class="masthead mb-auto">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3 class="masthead-brand">Portfolio: Zagster Client</h3>
        <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://felipecarreola.github.io/index.html">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://felipecarreola.github.io/introduction.html">Intro.</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://felipecarreola.github.io/hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn active">Portfolio</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://felipecarreola.github.io/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

              <ul class="dropdown-list">
                <li><a class="nav-link active" href="https://felipecarreola.github.io/zagster-client/">Zagster<br>Client</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>


    <section class="box-transp-zagster">
      <main role="main" class="inner cover">

        <h1 class="cover-heading">Zagster Bike Share in Bend</h1>
        <br>

        <div>
          <canvas id="myChart" width="490" height="490"></canvas>
        </div>

      </main>
    </section>


    <footer class="mastfoot mt-auto">
      <div class="box-transp-footer">
        <div class="inner">
          <p> Felipe Carreño Arreola || OSU Cascades Email: <a href="mailto:arreolaf@oregonstate.edu">arreolaf@oregonstate.edu</a> <br>
            <a href="https://github.com/FelipeCArreola" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1xG32b2.png"></a> <a href="https://github.com/FelipeCArreola" target="_blank">GitHub</a> ||
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/10423421/felipe-c-arreola?tab=profile" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/wO2A0jC.png"></a> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/10423421/felipe-c-arreola?tab=profile" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a> ||
            <a href="Files/Felipe Carreño Arreola_resume_Final.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rF2UoAi.png"></a> <a href="Files/Felipe Carreño Arreola_resume_Final.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One odd thing you're doing is defining functions 0-9 and then using function update...0-9. to invoke the functions just do updateChartData01(data). Don't put function in front of it

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my JS code ('$.when().then()'). I am now able to see my data requests populate on my console logs when pushed to my array. 
I still believe there is an asynchronous error possibly since my data is not updating my chart. 

*I am currently looking into dynamically  updating my chart.
-thank you again for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give this a try. I believe you are correct about asyncronous code and pushing to ChartData array causing things to not work as desired.

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://zagster-service.herokuapp.com"


const G5_TC = "/rides/count/g5"
const COL_TC = "/rides/count/columbia_simpson"
const DRAKE_TC = "/rides/count/drake_park"
const GALV_TC = "/rides/count/galveston"
const GRC_TC = "/rides/count/grc"
const OLD_TC = "/rides/count/old_mill"
const OSU_TC = "/rides/count/osu_cascades"
const TEN_TC = "/rides/count/ten_barrel"

var ChartData = [];


$(updateView)

function updateView() {

   $.when([
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + G5_TC, updateChartData)), 
            
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + COL_TC, updateChartData)), 
            
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + DRAKE_TC, updateChartData)),
         
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + GALV_TC, updateChartData)),
                    
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + GRC_TC, updateChartData)),
    
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + OLD_TC, updateChartData)),
               
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + OSU_TC, updateChartData)),
           
        ($.getJSON(BASE_URL + TEN_TC, updateChartData))
        
   ]).then(displayGraph);

}

function updateChartData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data
}
```

then change the definition of displayGraph to accept a parameter (this will be what is returned by the calls within the "when()" invocation. Also get rid of the global ChartData. Whenever you reference ChartData, instead reference this new chartData. Hope that helps!
edit: looking at the documentation for when(): https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ it appears as though you may need to do something more like this and then use allChartData like you were using ChartData.

```
 function displayGraph(chartData1, chartData2, chartData3, chartData4, chartData6, chartData7, chartData8) {
let allChartData = [chartData1, chartData2, chartData3, chartData4, chartData5, chartData6, chartData7, chartData8]
```

Comment: Thank you, Looking further into it. This will definitely help me out. Thank you again.